# FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/tiles.xml in WSO2AS 5.3 with java 8

Tags: java-8, wso2, jndi, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to deploy my application on WSO2 application server 5.3
I am using java 8 and changed my application name to ROOT.
I have deployed it on WSO2 5.1 with java 7 and it worked, whats changed WSO2 5.3
how do i solve the error of JNDI?

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate container.
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.contextInitialized(TilesListener.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:314)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:179)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:144)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: I/O error accessing source.
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UrlDefinitionsFactory.readDefinitions(UrlDefinitionsFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UrlDefinitionsFactory.init(UrlDefinitionsFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.initializeDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainer.java:406)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.init(BasicTilesContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createTilesContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:163)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.createContainer(TilesListener.java:90)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener.createContainer(StrutsTilesListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.contextInitialized(TilesListener.java:57)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/tiles.xml
    at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:384)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UrlDefinitionsFactory.readDefinitions(UrlDefinitionsFactory.java:286)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in carbon-deployment version 4.5.3.

- Bug in WSO2 JIRA: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-2188

It has reference for to pull-request with fixes for this bug.

To make it simpler to apply this fix for your current installation - I've applied only this fix to 4.5.3 and made another release with jar changed - you can get it here: https://github.com/akakunin/carbon-deployment/releases/tag/v4.5.3-WSAS-2188

Comment: Additionally, to fix this problem you also need fix for https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15785 - I've created another release for carbon-kernel 4.4.1 with only fix for this bug - you can find it here: https://github.com/akakunin/carbon-kernel/releases/tag/v4.4.1-CARBON-15785